# Proposing research as Ph.D. thesis in Sweden

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, thesis, sweden

I am a geography M.Sc. and I want to study Ph.D. in Sweden. I wrote a research proposal about a computer program which simulates some spatiotemporal situations. I have done some underlying logic and calculations too.

The problem is many many Ph.D. programs in Sweden are announced with special conditions. They demand that you work on a specific question or problem chosen by the authorities. But I want to work on my idea since I think it is so needed in geography.

Since in my country situations are completely different I am wondering: What's the solution?

Comment: Find a supervisor prepared to accept your topic. This may be very challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to PhD and postdoc positions there is essentially two types of positions, and some partially overlapping ones. The critical element here is where the money for the actual research is coming from. That is way more important than whatever idea you might have for a project.

So if the money is coming from:

1. a specific grant with certain goals and deadlines, then the PI (the principle investigator, i.e. the group leader) will have to show some results. S/He will want to have someone work on that project and nothing else
2. alternatively if it's core funding (from the faculty/university/private funding etc) then the money is not "earmarked" and the PI can pursue interesting ideas more freely.

So *assuming you are not bringing your own research funds*, if you really want to work on your own idea from day 1, and not willing to compromise on that, then your only option is to find someone that has plenty of money and not many ideas.

Not to sound too grim but you should know that it's a tall order

Comment: Or apply for a stipend. Or a grant. Or figure out funding in some other way. If you bring funding and an idea, it might be easier to find someone willing to provide mentoring and infrastructure.

Comment: @skymningen yes, of course. I took that for granted for a PhD student it would be difficult to bring your own funds. Thanks for the comment